# Query Between dates

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate Between '2016/05/21' AND '2016/05/20'
```

But it's not working...

the error :

> Additional information: Data type mismatch in criteria expression.

It is supposed to run on an Access table
and I activated it from c#.

The computer probably thinks it's a string, and not date...
how to fix that?

Comment: "SQL" is the family of languages. Which implementation are you actually using?

Comment: What SQL is this? Sql-Server? MySQL? Your dates could be backwards too...

Comment: "It's nit working" is not a description of your error. WHAT is not working? What's it doing? What did you expect?

Comment: You "tried this query"? What was the result?

Comment: Nota bene: SO can't read minds.

Comment: Much better! Still not including all info we need, though.

Comment: Oh I have no idea which sql...
it on access, if this help

and it crush

Comment: what else info I missed?

Comment: Ok I added more info

Comment: Check "[mcve]" for some initial guidance. Be sure to include the sql dialect you're using, help us set up a repro by providing example data, tell us about your collation/culture stuff (date times as strings depend on context). Provide a meaningful title. Tell us what you've tried, debugged, and found in the docs. Etc. (Finally, for so far language isn't a hurdle, try to put effort in spelling, grammar, and interpunction. Use a spellchecker if you need one. It's not a big thing, but it does make helping you more pleasant.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Access database engine interprets `'2016/05/21'` as a string value.  If you want it interpreted as a Date/Time value, use `#` instead of quotes.

```sql
SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate Between #2016/05/20# AND #2016/05/21#
```

Answer (score 0):

check your PC/Server date format and convert your dates in query LIKE

SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderDate Between CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2016/05/21', 103)  AND CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), '2016/05/22', 103)

here you can find formats 
http://www.sql-server-helper.com/sql-server-2008/sql-server-2008-date-format.aspx